# How does firefox choose which libavcodec to load?

Tags: rhel, firefox, plasma5

I'm running RHEL9 with plasma 5 as the desktop environment. Plasma pulls in `libavcodec-free` as a dependency. `libavcodec-free` installs `/usr/lib64/libavcodec.so.59` which as expected does not support mp4 decoding. I've already compiled and installed ffmpeg 4.4, which includes `libavcodec.so.58`. However, unless I remove the `/usr/lib64/libavcodec.so.59` (installed by `libavcodec-free`) firefox will continue to load it when attempting to decode an mp4 video and as a result the video will fail to play. If `/usr/lib64/libavcodec.so.59` is removed then firefox will load `/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.58` and play mp4 videos just fine. I've tried manually setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that `/usr/local/lib` is ahead of `/usr/lib64`, but this makes no difference.

I'm curious as to how firefox is deciding on which `libavcodec` to load and use to decode the mp4 videos since it does not seem to be based on the first available in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Really just looking to better understand how/why firefox is choosing the libavcodec-free version instead of the `ffmpeg` version.

Comment: I never figured out the root cause to this issue. Instead I just ended up removing the libavcodec.so.59 files provided by libavodec-free, then built and installed ffmpeg-5.1.4, which included the non-free version of libavcodec.so.59. mp4 videos play fine in firefox and other applications (e.g. spectacle) that use libavcodec.so.59 continue to function as expected.